# What meta http-equiv do I need for ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

What Meta http-equiv do I need for an ASP.NET page?

This is what I have for my HTML pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is HTML, it doesn't matter what (if any) server side program generates it.

`<meta charset="utf-8">` is sufficient though (although either should be backed up by a real HTTP content-type response header).

(This assumes you are using UTF-8 (you should be), which is not something determined by your choice of programming language / framework / etc).